# Can I use "reduction" and "cost" in plural form, as in the examples below?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

1. "Taxis and Ubers saw reductions in their costs per trip in Sydney over the time period."
2. "In terms of cost, bus and trains had the lowest, though their average costs increased throughout the period to 5 dollars and 10 dollars respectively."

Answer (score 1):

if you are simply comparing the cost at the end of a period with the cost at the start, I would use the singular with a definite article "a reduction". If you wish to indicate that there were multiple reductions in cost over the period, then a plural would be appropriate.

If you are talking about the various costs to the driver (fuel, maintenance, loan repayments, licensing fees, etc), then yes, you can use **costs**. If you are talking about the cost to the passenger, then it must be singular.

So, to compare the cost to the passenger at the start and the end of the period, you would say:

> Taxi and Uber users saw a reduction in their cost per trip in Sydney over the time period.

To make the same comparison for buses and trains:

> In terms of cost [per trip], buses and trains were lowest, though the average cost increased over the period to 5 and 10 dollars respectively.